# Proving that a well-ordered set with the order topology is not homeomorphic to any initial segment of it

Tags: general-topology

Let $\langle X,\leq_X\rangle$ be a well-ordered set. I want to show that $X$ with the topology on $X$ relative to $\leq_X$ (the order topology) is not homeomorphic to any initial segment of $X$. And then I need to conclude that any two well-ordered sets $\langle X,\leq_X\rangle$ and $\langle Y,\leq_Y\rangle$ are homeomorphic iff they are isomorphic. I can feel both seem true, but while the first one I don't know how to proof, the second one I can prove, but not as a conclusion of the first. Any ideas on how can I show the second one as a conclusion of the first?  And on how can I prove the first?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not true: $\omega+1$ and $\omega+2$ are homeomorphic. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/38993/462).

Comment: $< X,\leq_X>$ is even worse than most instances of the use of that symbol as a substitute for angle brackets.  I changed it to $\langle X,\leq_X\rangle$. ${}\qquad{}$