# Question about homeomorphism on ordinal spaces

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In my set theory class the professor said that if $\alpha$ is an ordinal of the form $\alpha=\kappa + \beta$,  where $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal and $\beta$ is an ordinal less than $\kappa$, then $[0,\alpha[$ is homeomorphic to $[0,\kappa[$.

I think that's no correct because $[0,\alpha[$ would be compact (because $\alpha$ is successor) and $[0,\kappa[$ no (because $\kappa$ is a limit ordinal). Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To complement Brian's answer, one can state precisely when two ordinals are homeomorphic. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/39004/462).

Comment: @Andrés: Ah, nice one; that was before I started here, and I hadn’t previously run across it.

Comment: @Brian Another interesting question is to classify those ordinals $\alpha$ such that if $\beta$ is homeomorphic to $\alpha$, then it contains a subset of type $\alpha$ and homeomorphic to $\alpha$ (Baumgartner would say that the subset is *order-homeomorphic* to $\alpha$).

Comment: The downvote on this question is hard to construe as anything but a display of ignorance: it’s an intelligent question with an obviously adequate context. The only other plausible explanation is vandalism for the sheer pleasure of it.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in thinking that the professor is mistaken, but it’s not true that $\alpha$ is necessarily a successor. What is true is that $[0,\alpha)$ is homeomorphic to the disjoint union of $[0,\kappa]$ and $[0,\beta)$, which is compact if and only if $\beta$ is a successor ordinal. If $\beta$ is a successor ordinal, $[0,\alpha)$ is homeomorphic to the ordinal sum $\beta+\kappa+1=\kappa+1$ and hence to $[0,\kappa]$, while $[0,\kappa)$ is not compact.

Comment: Thank you @Brian M. Scott !

Comment: @Ergonvi: You’re welcome!

Comment: By the by @Brian M. Scott, that result implies in particular that every closed sets of cardinality $\kappa$ is homeomoprhic to $[0,\alpha[$ ? Thanks.

Comment: @Ergonvi: You mean closed subsets of $[0,\alpha)$? Yes, if $\beta$ (and hence $\alpha$) is a successor ordinal.

Comment: @Ergonvi: My pleasure.