# Classification of subspace topologies of countably infinite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

For example, we know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is discrete, while $\mathbb{Q}$ is not. The former has no limit point, while for the latter, every point is a limit point. An intermediate object is $X_l=\{l\}\cup\{l+1/n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, which has only one limit point. I conjecture that for the desired classification, it suffices to see which point is a limit point, and that there are $2^{\mathbb{Z}}$ different subspace topologies. The operations such as $X_l\cup\mathbb{Z}$ increase a the number of limit points by one, and they may explicitly construct an arbitrary subspace topology from $\mathbb{Z}$.

Questions

- Are my conclusion and argument correct? If not, please answer the correct conclusion regarding the classification and justify it.
- For this classification, is there an explicit way to construct any such topology from the known objects such as $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$?

**Edit**
Qiaochu showed that limit points are not sufficient for classification. What tools would be needed?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/416672 for a very useful answer for the compact case.

Comment: Very informative! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book by Zemadeni (IIRC) Banach spaces of continuous functions, has a full proof of the standard classification of countable subspaces of the reals (or in fact countable metric spaces). The compact ones are countable ordinal numbers in essence, the others versions of this with $\mathbb{Q}$ as a dense in itself kernel.

The idea is to consider the scattering sequence for a countable space $X$. $X^{(1)} = X'$ (the set of limit points of $X$), $X^{(\alpha+1)} = (X^{(\alpha)})'$, for successor ordinals $\alpha +1$, and $X^{(\beta)} =\bigcap \{X^{(\alpha)} \alpha < \beta\}$ for limit ordinals $\beta$. This process stops on some countable ordinal $\gamma$ such that $X^{(\gamma)} = X^{(\gamma+1)}$. Then $X$ is uniquely determined by this $\gamma$ and if we end with the empty set, how many points there were on the stage before. (This is finite for a compact $X$ but can be countable discrete as well), or whether it ended in a countable dense in itself  space (which is $\mathbb{Q}$ essentially.)

So in that sense limit points are involved and important but we have to iterate the process. In fact, for this very reason ordinals were invented by Cantor. He came from analysis trying to analyse the possible countable sets of discontinuity of certain sums of goniometric series, and he needed ordinals to formulate his results, which led him to develop set theory for the first time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Good to know that it motivated Cantor to invent ordinals.

Answer (score 1):

It does not suffice to record which points are limit points. For example, the subspace given by

$$\{ -n, n \in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{ 0 \} \cup \left\{ \frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$$

and the subspace given by points of the form

$$\left\{ -\frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \cup \{ 0 \} \cup \left\{ \frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$$

both have the same limit point structure (one limit point "in the middle") but are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. So, limit points are irrelevant. But how can we classify?

Comment: Well, they're not irrelevant, they're just not enough. At each limit point you can in addition keep track of whether it is being approached from the left, from the right, or both. I don't know if this is enough or not.

Comment: Sorry for my sloppy use of the word. Thanks for input regarding the direction of the limit, which is really important. If this question is truly non-trivial and will not receive a decisive answer, I will migrate it to MO.