# Are topologies over a countably infinite set classified?

Tags: general-topology

I know that topological spaces over a given finite set are classified. But what about sets with cardinality $\omega$?  The only restriction I would require is for the spaces to be *$T_0$*, i.e. *have no topologically indistinguishable points*.

I initially thought that it would be sufficient to look at connected spaces, but then I realized that just because a space is disconnected, it need not be completely decomposable into connected components: Consider, for instance, $\{1/n\mid n\in \mathbb N_{>0}\}\cup \{0\}\subseteq \mathbb R$ equipped with the subspace topology: Every set of the form $[0,1/n]$ is clopen, but as their intersection $\{0\}$ is not open, there is no minimal clopen set around $0$, i.e. no connected subspace $S\subseteq X$ that admits a decomposition $X \simeq S \sqcup X\setminus S$.

Comment: In your example the components are all singletons and the space is just $\omega+1$, the second countabel ordinal. You seem to be confusing quasicomponents with components? The components are clear: no subset of more than one point is connected, so the maximal connected sets are singletons.

Comment: A connected component of a space isn't a minimal clopen subset, it's a **maximal connected** subset. Trivially every singleton is connected; in your example, the connected components are exactly the singletons. Moreover, *every* space can be decomposed into connected components, since the union of two connected sets with a point in common is again connected.

Comment: @NoahSchweber thanks for clearing that up, I should have known that. My line of intuition was that clopen sets are the ones that enable you to describe decompose your topological space into a coproduct of two substructures, so I somehow assumed that the “minimal version” of that corresponded to a connected component. Sorry about that.

Comment: However, in my remark I am not concerned about whether something is a connected component or not, but about if I can decompose the original topology with respect to that subspace. Which seems to me to be more interesting in a classification problem :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a classification for countable metric spaces (I sketch it in my answer to [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2264490/4280), they include all the countable ordinals and the rationals and combos of those), but beyond that it's isolated results: there are the 4 [countable Toronto spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto_space) that are not indiscrete, included and excluded point topologies, many different types of spaces based on an filters on $\omega$ (we already have more than continuum many homeomorphism types there), either using the filter as the topology, or its elements for a single non-isolated point aded to $\omega$ (but there could be more of those of Hausdorff is not required) etc etc. I also don't know what the homeomorphism type of a dense countable set of $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{R}$ is, and how many types there are (they are all crowded normal and of weight continuum). Etc. etc. Arens space is countable and quite interesting. The one-point compactification of the rationals, and countable connected Hausdorff spaces also exist. In [$\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Countable) you can look at more examples (often introduced to show specific combinations of properties are possible). There is much more variation than you'd think at first. A full classification seems far off as yet.

Comment: +1. Note to the OP that even the countable *closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$* are interesting; see e.g. the [Cantor-Bendixson derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set_property), which gives a way to "count the layers" in such a set (or many others!).

Comment: Thanks for the starting point, I wasn't aware of the metric classification! I wasn't ven sure whether I wanted to put the $T_1$-Restriction (let alone Hausdorff or metrizable or “countable subspace of $\mathbb R$”) into the question, but perhaps that was too ambitious.